# Can't launch vue3 requires vite cli, but it is downloaded, tell me what to do

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

```
PS C:\(...)\cofe-starbaks-copy-vue3> npm run dev
> cofe-starbaks-copy-vue@0.0.0 dev
> vite
```

I'm getting the following error when running the above command:

```
vite is not internal or external command, executable program, or batch file.
```

Comment: have you installed the node modules? try `npm install` first and then hit `npm run dev`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you follow the instructions here: https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application

Don't forget to have Node v16 installed, preferably with [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Then, you could run the following to have a successful Vue boilerplate

```
npm init vue@latest
```